# Unable to provide "Don't Allow" permissions handling on iOS 6 for Facebook 3.1 SDK/native account

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm working on an app that is both doing the app switching based login on iOS 5 and native logins under iOS 6. Unfortunately, the error that is provided back if the user doesn't allow access to the native account is the generic "login" error. For iOS 5, we don't normally handle this error because the user usually hit "Cancel" themselves, and we don't need to show any additional UI. But if the user already told iOS 6 to deny our app access to the token, this means we just quietly fail.

Is there a way we can tell when the login failure is due specifically to iOS's privacy settings and we can provide appropriate feedback? I've seen some samples posted here, but they don't provide iOS 6/iOS 5 specific behavior. I could also branch based on the version of iOS, but I just wanted to see if there was a more official way to make the distinction in the iOS SDK.

Comment: The answer to http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12712204/sdk-3-1-how-to-tell-whether-sdk-is-using-ios6-accounts-or-not also applies here.